# Using "attr()" on CSS pseudo elements in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9, pseudo-element

I'm using the pseudo element `:after` on my `H4` elements, and giving them an `attr('class')` for the `content` property:

```
<h4 class="category-label">This is a new event</h4>
```

with

```
h4:after
{
  content: attr(class);
  display: block;
  padding: 1em;
  background-color: #555;
}
```

will yield the expected results -- appropriate labels for `H4` elements *with* classes, and no labels whatsoever for `H4` elements *without* `class` attributes in <strike>most browsers</strike> Safari 5+.

However in IE9, `H4` elements without the `class` attribute still create block pseudo elements, resulting in blank gray boxes without text, which is not the expected behavior. In the image below, only the first block contains an `H4` with a `class` attribute, valued at "panel;" the other `H4` elements in the 2nd and 3rd blocks do not have any `class` attributes:

[image: IE9]

Is there a way to ensure that IE9 does not display pseudo content for parent elements that lack referenced content attribute? Pseudo elements w/o content should not render...

Comment: For the record, you should not be quoting the word `class`. The correct syntax is `attr(class)`, not `attr('class')`.

Comment: Absolutely right - sorry. My actual code is not quoted.

Comment: Also, this is expected behavior, so it's not an IE9 bug. It happens in other browsers that support generated content too (see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BoltClock/ztMSS)). I would explain why, but then I'd have to write a full-blown answer...

Comment: Ah - I checked the fiddle on Chrome and FF, and you're right. Same behavior as IE9. It seems I was testing on iOS and Safari 5+, which simply did not render the content if the attribute was missing. It's Safari with the unexpected behavior!

Comment: I'll just plug the relevant specifications here. Not very keen on adding an answer that explains the behavior but doesn't actually answer your question :| Look at the description of `attr()` here: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html#content then read this section: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-content/#inserting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just use

```
h4[class]:after
```

so the style will be applied only to the elements with a defined class

Comment: That worked splendidly - thanks very much. My alternative would have been something along the same lines, like `h4:not():after`, but I doubt that would have worked.

Comment: @atwixtor: Well, you can't use `:not()` to specify elements with an attribute. (You can use it to specify elements without an attribute e.g. `h4:not([class]):after`, but of course that goes the other way...)

Comment: :not even if the attr. being used with that CSS3 selector was a `class`? It was my hunch that I'd be targeting all H4 elements without a class or ID.

Comment: @atwixtor: `:not()` is supposed to take another simple selector as an argument in its brackets. Plus, as attributes are individual components of a DOM element, you can't really select an element with no attributes.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you can "ensure" it without using javascript to set its display. What is probably happening is a browser difference where the browsers acting as you expect are ignoring the `:after` and IE9 is treating the content as empty like `content: ''`

Comment: JavaScript can't handle CSS generated content either :/

Comment: Not directly, but to write css rules it can (which, admittedly, would be a horribly round about way to handle it), especially given Fabrizio's elegant solution.